# second "send" command in expect script is not waiting to finish the Output of first command

Tags: linux, expect

I have a very small expect script . The flow is as follows

1. `ssh` to remote machine
2. Execute a command and after executing the command you will be in a different prompt ( prompt name is `Enter cmd>`.
3. On the `Enter cmd>` prompt, I need to run many commands

Hence I designed this script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

 set FULL_CMD { #cmd1 #cmd2 #cmd3  }
 puts "STARTING......."

 log_file myfile.log ;# <<< === append output to a file
 spawn ssh tempuser\@dummyserver
 match_max  100000000

 expect "password:"
 send "temppasswd\r"
expect  "*temp*"
 send "cd \/home\r"
 expect "*temp*"
send "new cmd prompt\r"
expect "Enter cmd>"

foreach tempcmd $FULL_CMD {
 send "${tempcmd} \r "
 expect -exact  "Enter cmd>\r"
 send -- "\r"
expect eof }

send "q"
send "exit\r"

puts "I HAVE ENDED......."
```

**My problem:** Actually the O/P of first command `cmd#1` is very long and I can see that the expect script is not waiting for the O/P of the first command complete and is sending the second command `cmd#2` after some time.

This script works fine on systems where O/P of `cmd#1` is small, but on systems where the the O/P of `cmd#1` is very large (say 1000000 lines), it has trouble, i.e. it issues the first command `cmd#1` and the O/P follows, but before it get back to `Enter cmd>` prompt, the script issues the second command `cmd#2`

How can I ensure that command `cmd#2` is sent only after the output of `cmd#1` completes?

Answer (score 7):

Try setting a timeout at the start:

```
set timeout 60
```

or use `-1` to wait forever.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for suggestion. But as I understand Set timeout  / -1 is used for handling the ssh timeout/ hanging problem. But my issue is not related o ssh hanging / timeout. My problem  in the above script is  I am running #cmd1 #cmd2 #cmd3 from "Enter cmd>" prompt and while the #cmd1 is still running ( ie still producing the output) the script executes the second command #cmd2, ie the script does not wait for the output to complete for the first command

Comment: Well, the default timeout is 10 seconds. So try putting two commands in your array "sleep 20" and "sleep 20". Then run your job and see how long it takes. Then set the timeout to 60, as I suggested and run it again. You will soon see what is happening.

Comment: Hi mark, I want to make this as portable in other systems, however depending on internal system configuration , some have small output of #cmd1 and some have too long output.For example in some system the #cmd1 runs for 3 minustes ( say output is 1000000 lines)  where as in some the output is only few hundreds.So if I use sleep 3 mins, then it will be okey for the system which have longer output of #cmd1, but for the system which have smaller output of #cmd1 the script will wait for 3 mins to complete although the #cmd1 will be completed in 1 min. So script will idle for 2 mins unnecessarily

Comment: No, you are not understanding me. I was suggesting a quick test only. See if timeouts are the problem by temporarily changing your script to just execute "sleep 20" twice - that's all. If it runs in 40 seconds, timeouts are not the problem. If it runs in 20 seconds, the problem is that you need to change your timeout from the default of 10 seconds per command - which is what I suspect the issue with your real script is.

Comment: If a job takes 5 seconds and the timeout is 20 seconds, the following job will run after 5 seconds, so there is no penalty to having a bigger timeout - it only sets the MAX amount of time, if the command completes in less that is fine.

Comment: Hi Mark,Thanks for the suggestion. I am newbie to expect scripting language, can you please suggest where I should change the code and what should I put the value. the above is my real script. (unedited).in real situation, the #cmd1 in some systems take upto 3 mins to complete

Comment: Change #cmd1 to "sleep 20" and #cmd2 to "sleep 20"

Comment: i got that. Thanks mark.but the #cmd1 and #cmd2 are executed in the prompt "Emter cmd>", this is not bash prompt, So as i understand, if i replace #cmd1 and #cmd2  with sleep 20 it will be executed in "Enter cmd>" prompt. but this prompt "Enter cmd>" cannot handle sleep command, it can handle only few specific cmd. BTW I am going out of station and will be back day after tomorow. incase of any progress or any further suggestion from you please let me know. Thanks full to you as always

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your `foreach tempcmd $FULL_CMD` loop:

```
foreach tempcmd $FULL_CMD {
  send "${tempcmd} \r "
  expect -exact  "Enter cmd>\r"
  send -- "\r"
expect eof }
```

The problem is that you're `expect`ing `"Enter cmd>\r"`, but you will never get the `\r` in your output.

What you should `expect` is `"Enter cmd>$"`, where the `$` implies the end of the current command output (and not '\n`or '\r' or`eof`).

```
foreach tempcmd $FULL_CMD {
    send "${tempcmd} \r "
    expect -exact  "Enter cmd>$" # Check for spaces after '>' and fix as required
    send -- "\r"
    # expect eof
}
```

As for `expect eof`, it matches the end of the input stream which is connected to the output of the spawned process. It will only match once the spawned process terminates, thus it is of no use here

Answer (score -1):

Why do you have "expect eof" in your for loop?

```
foreach tempcmd $FULL_CMD {
  send "$tempcmd\r"
  expect "Enter cmd>"
  send -- "\r"         # why do you need this?
}
```

It's smart, while developing your program, to enable debugging: add this near the top: `exp_internal 1`

Comment: I have just copied the sample from one of the codes available in google. however in current scenarios in working system the script is halting for approx 5 secs before executing the next command ( system where #cmd1 O/P is small) but if i remove the expect eof then its not waiting at all, just running all the commands fast. So i preffered to use the expect eof.   About "send -- "\r" i was trying to change something to check if it works but still the same